# Adding dividers between list items in the menu.html.twig template

Tags: theming, 8, navigation

How do I add dividers between each `<li>` in the `menu.html.twig` template. Obviously with the code below, the divider also gets added after the last item, which isn't the desired result.

```
{% import _self as menus %}

{#
  We call a macro which calls itself to render the full tree.
  @see http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html
#}
{{ menus.menu_links(items, attributes, 0) }}

{% macro menu_links(items, attributes, menu_level) %}
  {% import _self as menus %}
  {% if items %}
    <ul class="loginbar pull-right">
    {% for item in items %}
      {%
        set classes = [
          item.is_expanded ? 'menu-item--expanded',
          item.is_collapsed ? 'menu-item--collapsed',
          item.in_active_trail ? 'menu-item--active-trail',
        ]
      %}
      <li{{ item.attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
        {{ link(item.title, item.url) }}
        {% if item.below %}
          {{ menus.menu_links(item.below, attributes, menu_level + 1) }}
        {% endif %}
      </li>
      <li class="topbar-devider"></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [The Loop Variable](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags//for.html#the-loop-variable) in the Twig docs; you can use something like

```
{% if loop.last == false %}
  <li class="topbar-devider"></li>
{% endif %}
```